# Anchoring a box2d body

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, physics, box2d-iphone

Is it possible to anchor a Box2D body to a specific X value, but still leave it able to move freely on the Y axis?  I feel like a prismatic joint may be necessary for this, but I had some trouble setting it up.
Thanks,

Tate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just limit the LinearVelocity

```
...//detect the velocity
b2Vec2 v = body->GetLinearVelocity();
v = b2Vec2(0,v.y);
body->SetLinearVelocity(v);
```